# Find closest match of image to +10.000 others with similar features

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, classification, object-recognition

I am trying to find the closest match of an image, to a large list of other images (+10.000). Background color is all white, same camera angle and the image content shape is close to each other (see image below). I tried using `opencv` and `ORB` and `BFMatcher` with `knnMatch` to find the closest match. But I am not even close to find the match I want.

To my understanding, images needs to be greyscale, but in my case I think colors would be a very important descriptor?

I am new to both opencv and image matching, so can you help me to if I need to use another approach?

```
import cv2
import os
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000) # Find 1000 features to match from 
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

# Image to match
findImg = 'captainA.png'
imgCur = cv2.imread(f'{"Images"}/{findImg}', 0)
kp1,des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgCur,None)

# Loop through all superheroe images and find closest match
images = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png","img4.png","img5.png","img6.png","img7.png","img8.png","img9.png","img10.png","img11.png","img12.png"]

matchList = []
names = []
for img in images:
    imgCur = cv2.imread(f'{Superheroes}/{img}', 0)
    kp2,des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgCur,None)
 
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
    goodMatches = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance: # Use 75 as a threshold defining a good match
            goodMatches.append([m])
    matchList.append(len(goodMatches))
    names.append(img)

matchIdx = matchList.index(max(matchList))
    
# Name of matched image
print(names[matchIdx])
```

What I want to find:

[image]

Comment: if color is important you can convert your RGB images to HSV and apply the descriptor to the H channel (but then you will lose information about saturation and value). If you need all this info you can apply the descriptor the the three color channels R,G,B and concatenate the descriptors into a larger one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval you'll need clustering. this is not easy. there might be open source libraries that implement this (saw some attempts) but I don't know how well they work.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz that looks very promising, thanks. I will try to find an open source library and come back with an update.

Comment: neural networks might be required. simple features like SIFT might be able to capture some local properties but they can't "see" the character/identity. those two figures you pointed out aren't the *same* object, so anything "matching" those two would need to accept such differences in appearance (deformations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small code there should do the job.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('fc1').output)

def extract(img):
    img = img.resize((224, 224)) # Resize the image
    img = img.convert('RGB') # Convert the image color space
    x = image.img_to_array(img) # Reformat the image
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    feature = model.predict(x)[0] # Extract Features
    return feature / np.linalg.norm(feature)

# Iterate through images and extract Features
images = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png","img4.png","img5.png"...+2000 more]
all_features = np.zeros(shape=(len(images),4096))

for i in range(len(images)):
    feature = extract(img=Image.open(images[i]))
    all_features[i] = np.array(feature)

# Match image
query = extract(img=Image.open("image_to_match.png")) # Extract its features
dists = np.linalg.norm(all_features - query, axis=1) # Calculate the similarity (distance) between images
ids = np.argsort(dists)[:5] # Extract 5 images that have lowest distance
```

Comment: A way to make this faster obviosuly, is to precalculate features for your "database" of images, another thing is that you probably can do some stuff here in parallel, I think numpy already does some using SIMD

Comment: I tried with this solution but it does not recognising the images now.