# Fast method for key-point based image matching [Python]

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, cbir

The scenario is, Let's suppose I took random images from my Gallery and put in some folder, and also print these image in hard form. Now I turned on my laptop camera and place an image in front of camera, My code need the tell the name of matching image from the folder. Actually the code I have add in the question works fine but when I increases the number of image in folder then Identification start taking more time. I want to know, is there any method that I can try to improve my speed? Here is the working [Demo](https://youtu.be/TsIGrC_A2uU) of my scenario.

```
import cv2
import os
from pathlib import Path
import time


# Define path
pathImages = 'ImagesQuery'

# Set the Number of detected Features
orb = cv2.ORB.create(nfeatures=1000)

# Set the threshold of minimum Features detected to give a positive, around 20 to 30
thres = 27

# List Images and Print out their Names and how many there are in the Folder
images = []
classNamesImages = []
myListImages = os.listdir(pathImages)

print(myListImages)
print('Total Classes Detected', len(myListImages))
# this will read in the images
for cl in myListImages:
    imgCur = cv2.imread(f'{pathImages}/{cl}', 0)
    images.append(imgCur)
    # delete the file extension
    classNamesImages.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNamesImages)


# this will find the matching points in the images
def findDes(images):
    desList = []
    for img in images:
        kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
        desList.append(des)
    return desList

# this will compare the matches and find the corresponding image
def findID(img, desList):
    image_matching_time = time.time()

    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matchList = []
    finalVal = -1
    try:
        for des in desList:
            matches = bf.knnMatch(des, des2, k=2)
            good = []
            for m, n in matches:
                # the distance of the matches in comparison to each other
                if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
                    good.append([m])
            matchList.append(len(good))
    except:
        pass
    # uncomment to see how many positive matches, according to this the thres is set
    # print(matchList)

    if len(matchList) != 0:
        if max(matchList) > thres:
            finalVal = matchList.index(max(matchList))
    print("matching time --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - image_matching_time))
    return finalVal


desList = findDes(images)
print(len(desList))

# open Webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:

    success, img2 = cap.read()
    imgOriginal = img2.copy()
    # convert Camera to Grayscale
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# if Matching with Image in List, send the respective Name
    id = findID(img2, desList)

    if id != -1:
        # put text for the found Image
        cv2.putText(imgOriginal, classNamesImages[id], (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    # show the final Image
    cv2.imshow('img2', imgOriginal)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I have tried with [deep learning base solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71764494/find-closest-match-of-image-to-10-000-others-with-similar-features) but it did't work. Second I have tried **FLANN** feature matcher its showing the same time delay 0.4 sec as in upper shown code. I am looking for any fast solution. Here is a sample of original image from folder and query image from the camera.

[Edit]:
Number of query images is around 1000 and I want to compare 20 fps with all query images.

[image]

Comment: show your data. then we can discuss approaches. -- why do you stop after feature matching? where is Lowe's ratio test? where is the model finding (homography or lesser)? why do you stick with outdated, underperforming feature descriptors like ORB?

Comment: that "Demo" video you link to appears to be spam. what are we supposed to see there that is relevant to your question?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have added wrong link mistakenly, Now I have updated this demo link

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am new to this field and that's why I found this solution. My data is some images and I have printed these same image on paper, Now when I place a printed picture in front of camera code need to tell the file name matched with the printed image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think my code is very clear, you get the idea what I am trying to achive.

Comment: I'll respond when you've addressed my questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249767/discussion-between-qazi-ammar-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Comment: Have a look at this repo: it does what you're looking for. It solves the matching on scale performance problem using K-D Trees.
`https://github.com/introlab/find-object`

Comment: Could you please upload your original images, i.e., the ones you plotted? Also, why is your camera image in grayscale?

Comment: I have make both images in grayscale during code you can see.

Comment: for context, this is Content Based Image Retrieval: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? In real life approach: I did it for ten images, now I want to do for thousands or millions - doesn’t work. You have to specify requirement in terms of number of images, processing time and cost, size of images, their quality. Don’t expect your solution to scale even x10 from what you designed and implemented

Comment: @ivan_onys I have updated the question and add the number of images and time computation for these images.